# ¿Como calcular el promedio de las diferencias entre marcas de tiempo en php?

Tags: php, datetime, diff

Buenas tardes, esta es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta.

Tengo un array de datos con marcas de tiempos.
En primer lugar estoy calculando la ***diferencia de tiempo*** entre cada una de esas marcas. Ese calculo lo estoy haciendo utilizando la funcion --diff-- del objeto  --DateTime--

```
        $range = Array (
             '2018-01-18 18:52:31',
             '2018-01-18 18:54:30',
             '2018-01-18 18:57:42',
             '2018-01-18 19:05:02',
             '2018-01-18 19:10:01',
             '2018-01-18 19:15:05');
        $lastReg = null;
        $Tiempos = array();

        foreach ($range as  $log) {
            # code...
            if($index != 0){
                $datetime1 = new DateTime($log);
                $datetime2 = new DateTime($lastReg);
                $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                array_push($Tiempos,$interval);
            }

        }
```

pero ahora quiero calcular el promedio de tiempo entre esas diferencias.

Se me ocurre recorrer los ***$Tiempos*** he ir obteniendo de alguna forma el valor en segundos de cada uno y sumarlo pero no se como hacerlo...

Gracias por sus opiniones.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Mientras más datos des, tendrás más posibilidades de una respuesta precisa. Si dices: *tengo un array de datos con marcas de tiempos...*, ¿podrías mostrar un pequeño ejemplo del contenido del array, al menos los datos importantes para este caso? Luego dices: *ahora quiero calcular el promedio de tiempo entre esas diferencias*. ¿El promedio global  o el promedio entre cada fila del array?

Comment: el promedio de tiempo entre las diferencias calculadas.

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular el promedio de un array numérico:

```
<?php

$num = [2, '2', 2];
$promedio = array_sum( $num ) / count( $num );

print_r( $promedio ); // Resultado: 2
```

[+ info sobre `array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php)

Para solucionar el error `Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string` tienes que convertirlo antes con [`$interval->format('%a')`](http://php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php):

Tú código:

```
if($index != 0){
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($log->created_on);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($lastReg->created_on);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

    array_push($Tiempos, (int)$interval->format('%a'));
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa2c97e97f8a3df499d8e6848da95c5377d1d7d6)**</kbd>

Comment: En este caso lo que estoy almacenando son objetos del tipo DateInterval Php(http://cl.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) salta un error por que array_sum() necesita un array de número

Comment: @ThrTill - Porque lo tienes que convertir `$interval->format('%a')`... rectifico la respuesta

Comment: @ThrTill - Listo... revísalo y me cuentas.. saludos

Comment: Listo. muchas gracias.